# Why can't I calculate percentage discount from this HTML table in JS?

Tags: javascript

As a beginner, I've been trying to get this to 01) generate the discount value; 02) Calculate the resulting value, as the user informs the percentage, but it gives me `number` as type, then `NaN` right after it.

```js
function grand_total(el) {
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let termsTotal = 0;
  let dollarUS = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
  });


  if (el) {
    let total = 0;
    total += parseFloat(document.getElementById('totalValue').innerText);
    console.log('Type Total: ' + typeof total);

    console.log(total);

    let percentage = 0;
    percentage += parseInt(el.value);
    console.log('Percentage: ' + JSON.stringify(percentage))
    console.log('Percentage Type:  ' + typeof percentage)

    if (percentage > 0) {
      termsTotal = (percentage / 100) * total;
      grandTotal = total - termsTotal;
    }

    console.log('Terms Total: ' + JSON.stringify(termsTotal))
    console.log('Grand Total: ' + JSON.stringify(grandTotal))
    document.getElementById('termsTotal').innerText = termsTotal
    document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerText = grandTotal
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <tr>
    <td id="totalTitle" colspan="10" align="right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
    <td id="totalValue" class="total">$7.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="termsRow" colspan="9" align="right"><strong>Deposit(%):</strong></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="terms" name="numberInputs" value="30" onchange="grand_total(this)"></td>
    <td id="termsTotal" class="terms_total">NaN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="grandTotalRow" colspan="10" align="right"><strong>Grand Total:</strong></td>
    <td id="grandTotal" class="grand_total">NaN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Apperciate any help.

Comment: You need to remove the `$` before calling `parseFloat()`.

Comment: The `<input>` has to be inside a `<td>`. And all this HTML needs to be inside `<table>` and `<tr>`. Please post valid HTML.

Comment: All the following calculations will be wrong because `parseFloat()` can't parse a number that begins with `$`.

Comment: I recommend using a variable to store the totals. Then just writing that variable to the screen instead of pulling the values from the DOM. This process allows you to display it however you want without worrying about any characters messing with the calulations.

Comment: You're right! Corrected it, @Barmar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip the dollar sign out of the text you are trying to convert to a number first. You can do that with `Number(document.getElementById('totalValue').innerText.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,''));`

```js
function grand_total(el) {
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let termsTotal = 0;
  let dollarUS = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
  });

  if (el) {
    let totalValue = Number(document.getElementById('totalValue').innerText.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,''));
    let total = 0;
    total += parseFloat(totalValue);
    console.log('Type Total: ' + typeof total);

    console.log(total);

    let percentage = 0;
    percentage += parseInt(el.value);
    console.log('Percentage: ' + JSON.stringify(percentage))
    console.log('Percentage Type:  ' + typeof percentage)

    if (percentage > 0) {
      termsTotal = (percentage / 100) * total;
      grandTotal = total - termsTotal;
    }
    console.log('Terms Total: ' + JSON.stringify(termsTotal))
    console.log('Grand Total: ' + JSON.stringify(grandTotal))
    document.getElementById('termsTotal').innerHTML = termsTotal
    document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerHTML = grandTotal
  }
}

document.querySelector('.terms').addEventListener('change',function(){
  grand_total(this);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="totalValue" class="total">$17.75</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="terms" name="numberInputs" value="30" /></td>
    <td id="termsTotal" class="terms_total"><strong></strong></td>
    <td id="grandTotal" class="grand_total"><strong></strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw only the number in the logs here and thought that stripping $ wasn't needed!

Answer (score 1):

First change `td` tag to `span` or `div` element as `td` is a part of `table` tag and remove "$"

```js
function grand_total(el) {
    let grandTotal = 0;
    let termsTotal = 0;
    let dollarUS = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
    });

    if (el) {
      let total = 0;
      total += parseFloat(document.getElementById("totalValue").innerText);
      console.log("Type Total: " + typeof total);

      console.log(total);

      let percentage = 0;
      percentage += parseInt(el.value);
      console.log("Percentage: " + JSON.stringify(percentage));
      console.log("Percentage Type:  " + typeof percentage);

      if (percentage > 0) {
        termsTotal = (percentage / 100) * total;
        grandTotal = total - termsTotal;
      }
      console.log("Terms Total: " + JSON.stringify(termsTotal));
      console.log("Grand Total: " + JSON.stringify(grandTotal));
      document.getElementById("termsTotal").innerHTML = termsTotal;
      document.getElementById("grandTotal").innerHTML = grandTotal;
    }
  }
```

```html
<span id="totalValue" class="total">17.75</span>
<input
  type="number"
  min="0"
  class="terms"
  name="numberInputs"
  value="30"
  onchange="grand_total(this)"
/>
<br />
<span id="termsTotal" class="terms_total"><strong></strong></span>
<br />
<span id="grandTotal" class="grand_total"><strong></strong></span>
```